# Toggle all in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items that can be selected:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="selected = false" ng-click="selected = !selected">
    ...
</div>
```

I want a simple checkbox outside of the list that will select all of the items IN the list. What's the prettiest Angular way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function in your controller to loop through each `item` in your `items` array and set its `selected` property to true.  Here's a sample of the function:

```
$scope.selectAll = function(selected) {
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
        item.selected = selected;
    });
}
```

I made the function take an argument so you can re-use it to do an de-select all.

Next, you can create a button that will call this function, passing `true` as an argument.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="selectAll(true)">Select All</button>
```

Here's a very rudimentary jsfiddle for it:  http://jsfiddle.net/x906p4qx/

Hope it helps!